# How to fire a new http request only when the first one is completed and ignore/cancel all the other requests in between

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest, rxjs

I am making the front-end of an SPA with Angular2 and I have a database with lots of records and the database itself is very slow, so taking 10000 records (or just the last 10 of them with ORDER BY) takes up to 4-5 seconds. In my situation upgrading a database is not an option.

So what I want to do is: when a user clicks on paginator's "next" button (onNextClick is already called) multiple times (let's say he is continuously clicking up to 100 times or more), only the first http request would be sent to the Server/API. Now is the part where I can't manage to figure it out:

WHEN the first request comes back with a result, THEN the last clicked event fires a new request ignoring all other click requests in between the first and the last one (ignored should be requests, but not the clicks themselves). THEN, if the user is still clicking, the last click/request becomes the first one and so on...

I tried to do that with RxJS, but I only managed to do that by using interval, so if interval is 600 ms and the user is clicking every 1000ms, all the requests are sent to server. Here's my code:

```
 private clickStream = new Subject();

 ngOnInit() {
   this.clickStream
   .debounce(() => Observable.interval(600).take(1))
   .subscribe(
     params => {
       this.callHttpPostMethod();
     }
   );
 }

 onNextClick(event) {
     this.clickStream.next(event);
 }
```

Any Angular2 solution would be welcome - using RxJS is not a requirement.

Comment: Retrieving 10,000 records should not be taking 4-5 seconds. Consider tuning your DB indexes, so that it returns data < 1s.

Comment: Have a look at this recipe in the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/26559/discarding-slow-outdated-rest-calls#t=20170314093917710946

Comment: I agree about DB indexes, but I'm not sure it would help, since sorting in front-end is enabled on ~30 of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cancel in-flight requests and ensure that only the latest request is being handled by using [switchMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap):

```
this.clickStream
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap(e=> this.callHttpPostMethod())
    .subscribe(t=> {
          ... do something ...
     });
```

Comment: Just for additional clarification: You __can__ cancel requests (by unsubscribing a running observable) and `switchMap` __does__ cancel running requests by unsubscribing, whenever a new data-emission happens "up stream" - if you are not using a super-old InternetExplorer you can even see in the network-tab that the status of such a request "Canceled"

Comment: Looks like switchMap was what I needed, thanks!! BTW, did you mean .debounceTime(500)? Because I get error when I try .debounce(500)